# Ext.MessageBox.confirm inside iFrame don't scroll to the centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I've got an iframe with height set in `window.onload` event. There are many rows with an option to delete. When delete link is clicked `Ext.MessageBox.confirm` is displayed and always scrolls to centre of the iframe.

Is it possible not to scroll to the centre when confirm box appears, just stay in the position when it was clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution a bit hackish but works for me:

When page is used inside iframe call `Ext.MessageBox.confirm` on outer page. When confirmed, call confirmed logic inside iframe.

I'm accepting this as solution, unless someone gives easier or better one.